# Simultaneously Tracking Head and Front Facing Camera Transforms Possible?

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm currently experimenting with various AR/Computer vision libraries such as ARCore,Firebase ML Kit and  OpenCV in Unity3D. I'd like to recreate a person holding a selfie camera in a 3D scene which requires tracking both the person's head and the camera transforms, without requiring some kind of external sensors such as the HTC Vive's Room Sensors. Only the on device sensors of the front camera, gyro, accelerometer etc.

I only care about the front half sphere space in front of the person that allows the user to move the phone in 90 degrees in any direction (see image). We can also assume the face is always detected by the front facing camera. I've had some success but only when adding the constraints of one of the elements remaining stationary. ARCore's AugmentedFace provides a face transform in camera space but it doesn't seem to provide the camera's world transform.Does anybody know if this is even possible?

[image]